# How to change size of the background color on hover for the following code?

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS hover and menu, as you can see here

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "6vw";
```

```css
$brandColor: darkorchid;
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $brandColor, darken($brandColor, 15%));
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #252e38;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  margin: auto 0;
  border: thick #FFAA03;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  /*display:inline-block;*/
}

.menu ul li {
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  /*padding-top: 25px;*/
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  /*margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;*/
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
  /*    padding: 2px 10px;  /*newly added code*/
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0ab2d2;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*hover is not fully correct*/
  /*padding: 27px 7px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <!--<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>--></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="3">Home</li>
      <li class="3">About Us</li>
      <li class="3">Blog</li>
      <li class="3">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="socialIcon">

  </div>
  <div class="searchIcon">

  </div>
</header>
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Software_ss/pen/YzqmRMb

on hover the background color changes but on small size.

How I can change its background size on hover something like this menu? What
I need to change, I not understanding, please help.

```
https://mofizuddin12.github.io/Nemo-ipsam-voluptatem-H.W/
```

Comment: You mean, you want the entire menu to change color on hover, or just want the hover to be bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `padding-right: 15px;` you can add padding all around the element with `padding: 15px;`. `padding-right` will only add `15px` space to the right inner side of your element box, but to produce the effect that you want, you need to apply the space all around your inner box.

So instead of

```css
.menu ul li{
   padding-right: 15px;
   /* rest of its style */
}
```

your code should be like this:

```css
.menu ul li{
   padding: 15px;
   /* rest of its style */
}
```

And its final form would be something like this:

```css
$brandColor: darkorchid;
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $brandColor, darken($brandColor, 15%));
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #252e38;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  margin: auto 0;
  border: thick #FFAA03;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menu ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #0ab2d2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="3">Home</li>
      <li class="3">About Us</li>
      <li class="3">Blog</li>
      <li class="3">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

**NOTE:** You can read more about how `padding` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Answer (score 1):

Change your current .menu ul li to this:

```
.menu ul li{
    margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
    color: white;
    /*padding-top: 25px;*/
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    /*margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;*/
    padding-top: auto;
    padding-bottom: auto;
}
```

As for explanation. Instead of the padding-right you use, you can use margin-right in order to create space **outside** of the element. Padding creates space **inside** of the element. The more padding you give, the bigger the background becomes on hover.